# Why there is no @Implements annotation in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I have found the `@Override` annotation very much helpful while overriding some super class methods in my derived classes. Basically the compiler detects the flaws in my program early which is always a good thing . But why there is no @Implements annotation in Java ?

Comment: `@Override` is kind of a formality; it's not really needed.  The compiler isn't going to fail if you don't have that annotation.  When you're *implementing* an interface, however...the compiler will scream out if you're not implementing every defined method in that interface.

Comment: @Makoto - I suspect he means his IDE rather than the compiler. That said, if you were to do `javac -Xlint:overrides` (or just `-Xlint`) it *would* tell you about it, so maybe he's doing that.

Comment: (would tell you about it if you made an error when overriding, I should say).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because you use `@Override` for methods defined by interfaces as well.

(Yes, you're "implementing" rather than "overriding" ... but `@Override` is used for both)

Comment: @RyanStewart - That is true, but since we're 6 years past release and in fact at EOL for 6 I really have stopped qualifying anything unless it's a 6 vs. 7 thing :)

Comment: Yet, sadly, in the last year (4 years after the last comment) I had to port code to Java 5 so it could run inside Oracle 11. Old Javas never die, they just hide in wait for the unwary.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 6 you can use @Override on class methods implementing methods defined in interfaces

Answer (score 1):

To implement an interface we use `implements` and if any method exists in that interface then we override those methods to provide an implementation.

So there is only `@Override` annotation because in both cases (class or interface) we always override.

Answer (score 0):

To implement an interface the keyword already exists: `implements`. but for override, no such keyword existed. `@Override` is not a keyword but works similar.