# Why do we need to override abstract methods from an interface?

Tags: java, android

Why do we need to override an abstract method if there is no method definition in the first place?

Here is a snippet from an Android project.

```java
public class SampleClickListener implements OnClickListener {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       // custom implementation
   }
}
```

`OnClickListener` is an interface with an abstract method `onClick()`. So there was no method definition previously set. What are we overriding exactly?

On second thought this might just be syntactical thing. Am I right to say that I'm *overriding* even without the `@Override` symbol as long as I declare the same exact method name with same number of param argument with same type?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking why `@Override` isn't called `@Implement` on abstract methods?

Comment: @shmosel Ha, thanks for throwing that thought. I got my question answered through this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869039/why-there-is-no-implements-annotation-in-java

Comment: @LeoKim : This is the concept of inheritance and abstraction. You might need to override some function definition in your derived class. Same terminology is followed in interface implementation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here by default your ide will add this method to `SampleClickListener`, and you need to add on click implementation for your application here.
Using override is not necessary, but it is highly recommended. It warns you when you write a function that you think overrides another one but you misspelled something.

Answer (score 0):

May be the answer for that is because public class SampleClickListener is a seperate class which you override this public void onClick(View view) {
// custom implementation}

Note Onclick is an attribute for a button type.